# How do I navigate to an external URL using reference tags?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component

```
<a href='{!v.Url__c}'>{!v.Url__c}</a>
```

My component currently has the code above. How do I navigate to a new tab with the URL? I tried adding http:// and // to the front of v.URL__c but it isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried setting `target="_blank"` as an additional attribute?

Comment: A new window is opened, but the url gets appended to the end of my salesforce org url.

Comment: What is the actual value of the `Url__c` field?

Comment: It doens't include http://, just www.google.com

Comment: Okay so if the URL does include http://, it works. Is there any way to validate that on the Detail page?

Comment: Sure, you could do `href="{!IF(BEGINS(v.URL__c, 'http', v.URL__c, 'http://' & v.URL__c))}"`.

Comment: Isn't compiling for me. Could it be because it's a lightning component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48216/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right syntax for lightning components

```
<a href="{!'https://'+v.Url__c}">link</a>
```

Comment: What if it already starts with `http(s)://`?

Comment: then it can be like this {!v.Url__c} .To accomodate both one can write formula field